# .php file is not being viewed in all browsers

Tags: php, mysql, http-status-code-404

I am changing my website to .php files instead of .html files, but the file with .php extension is not showing in the browser - it is giving me 404 error - file not found. Does that mean that php is not enabled at the webserver.

Comment: "0 down vote"...is that a plea for mercy?

Comment: Honestly?  You're probably typing the address wrong.

Comment: What webserver are you using? Is it yours or a hosted service? Most the stuff I put on BlueHost comes back with a 404. It isn't because I did anything wrong. It's because BlueHost is a piece of....

Comment: Webservers will send out any file which matches the request in the URL. If you get a 404 on a particular url (say /site/blah.php), then there's no 'blah.php' in your /site directory.

Comment: Maybe your server does specific rewrite on your url and look at the wrong place.

Answer (score 2):

A [404 error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404) means the requested resource doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

If it was not enabled I do not think that it would give you a 404 error, it should just come up with nothing. Try copying the web address from the FTP server and pasting it in the browser, maybe its in the wrong location.

Answer (score 0):

A php file doesn't have to contain any actual php code. As far as I know, the web server will still serve the page if it exists and not give a 404. It's more likely you'd see an internal server error 500 than a 404 if php wasn't on the server.

So, you're probably just typing the address wrong. Just double check the file's location on your web server and make sure it's actually there. Don't forget the .php extension.

Comment: You'd still need to tell the server that .php is text/html, otherwise it'll go out as application/octet-stream or something and simply be downloaded instead of being viewed in-browser.

Comment: @Marc very true. that is what will happen.